# Segmentation fault core dump, Pointers and Structs

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
 void group(char *chars, int v)
{
      int gid = atoi(chars);
      struct group *g = malloc(sizeof(struct group));
      g = getgrgid(gid);
      printf("file group: %s (gid: %d\n", g->gr_name, gid);
      return;
}
```

the segmentation fault should be occuring for g->gr_name. But ive done this before and it didn't cause a problem. what should i do to change it?

Comment: is chars non-null? Why are you doing malloc at first place, use `struct group *g=getgrgid(gid);` After call make sure `g != NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mohid points out, you're `malloc`ing a `struct group` and then leaking it by immediately replacing the pointer.

`getgrgid()` returns a pointer to an **already existing** entry, **or** `NULL` if no entry is found, or an error occurs. You need to check for error conditions. At the very least, something like:

```
void group(char *chars, int v)
{
      int gid = atoi(chars);
      struct group *g = getgrgid(gid);
      if (g)
      {
          printf("file group: %s (gid: %d)\n", g->gr_name, gid);
      }
      else if (errno)
      {
          printf("error checking gid (gid: %d)\n", gid);
      }
      else
      {
          printf("no entry for gid: %d\n", gid);
      }
}
```